# Extracting datetime pattern from string based on culture

Tags: .net, string, datetime, extract

I have to extract datetime pattern from string date.

E.G.
I have datetime string "2020.01.01-09:20"
I parse this string using culture

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
var date = "2020.01.01-09:20";
var isParsed = DateTime.TryParse(date, culture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out var result);
```

Result is correct.
Now I have to make some random changes in date and time and parse it back to string with pattern extracted from original string.

I make a method that contains all patterns for culture

```
private static IList<string> GetDateTimePatterns(CultureInfo culture)
{
    var info = culture.DateTimeFormat;
    return new string[]
    {
        info.FullDateTimePattern,
        info.LongDatePattern,
        info.LongTimePattern,
        info.ShortDatePattern,
        info.ShortTimePattern,
        info.MonthDayPattern,
        info.ShortDatePattern + " " + info.LongTimePattern,
        info.ShortDatePattern + " " + info.ShortTimePattern,
        info.YearMonthPattern,
        info.SortableDateTimePattern
    };
}
```

The result of

```
foreach (var pattern in GetDateTimePatterns(culture))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(pattern ,culture));
    }
```

generates output:

```
Wednesday, January 1, 2020 9:20:00 AM
Wednesday, January 1, 2020
9:20:00 AM
1/1/2020
9:20 AM
January 1
1/1/2020 9:20:00 AM
1/1/2020 9:20 AM
January 2020
2020-01-01T09:20:00
```

As you see there is no pattern that is the same as original string.

How to extract correct pattern depending on culture ?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a custom pattern. You can use infinitely many custom patterns and the environment cannot foresee each and every pattern that you may use. Possible solutions

## You may create additional patterns

Since [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=net-5.0) is [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed), you may not create a class that inherits from it, but you can create a new class, having some properties of patterns that you may expect.

## You may use Levenshtein's distance

[Levenshtein's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is the number of single-character edits that is needed in order to reach string2 starting from string1. You may calculate this distance of your input string for each pattern's version and choose the minimum, as that pattern is the closest.

Comment: But i dont know how pattern would look like. Its become from OCRed files that are written by humans. That isnt any standard. I have patters that are specially created when it doesnt parsed by culture... then i iterate by this patters and check. But when its parsed by culture i have to recreate string basing on pattern from culture.

Comment: @HD my answer did not assume that you know what the pattern is. However, if there are no restrictions for the format, then it's difficult to do anything reliably. For example 01/02/03 could mean six separate things, depending on which the year, month and day slot is. So, you can compare the Levenshtein's distances and choose the minimum. However, in formats such as in my example it's difficult to find out what is the year, month and day unless you have some further information.

Comment: But when i Parse it to DateTime using Culture the logic know what to do with every seperated "thing". Even when i extract pattern there is problem that some things are not 1:1. E.g SortableDateTimePattern: 'yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss' contain i patter T (terminator) that could be whitespace, underscore, hyphen. So based on pattern i cant recreate exact the same string with chanded values... Because Parsing handle the input string correctli it must be a way to extract usable pattern to parse it back to string

Comment: @HD this is why you need to find the Levenshtein distance. Your code will have to try several combinations. Okay, if it's four digits, then it's obviously a year. But if it's two digits, then it can be at least a month or a day. So, your algorithm will need to try to identify what's identifiable from the actual value. 'Wednesday', for example is a clear indication of a day, so, if the input contains 02, that's certainly not a day as long as the day has already been found. So: 1. Identify what's identifiable 2. Make sequential guesses for what is not certain 3. Compare Levenshtein for guesses.

Comment: To be honest i dont know how could i use Levenstain algorithm... I have original string and you want to generate strings using all patterns in culture and choose that one wchich has the lowest distance... and what then ?

Comment: @HD Levenshtein's algorithm is publicly available. I recommend to make a few possible patterns. For example: 2020.01.01-09:20 -> yyyy.mm.dd-hh:MM and 2020.01.01-09:20 -> yyyy.dd.mm:hh:MM. There are only two possibilities in this case. Compare this to the patterns that you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226976/discussion-between-h-d-and-lajos-arpad).